# Iframe do Google Maps não está mostrando a marcação do local

Tags: php, jquery, html, google-maps

Há uma parte no meu site onde existe um `select` com vários lugares do Brasil. Ao selecionar um lugar, logo abaixo tem um `iframe` com o GoogleMaps que automaticamente atualiza para a coordenada correspondente ao local selecionado.

O problema é que algumas coordenadas não aparecem direito. O local indicado é diferente do correto, talvez porque o local não esteja cadastrado no Google ou porque realmente não foi mapeado.

Em alguns casos até mostra a área correta do local, mas sem nenhuma marcação. Exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Deveria ter um marcador no meio desse terreno marrom.

O código para o `iframe` que estou utilizando é este:

```
<iframe width="734" height="302" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com.br/maps?ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=&amp;t=m&amp;iwloc=A&amp;ll=COORDENADA_AQUI&amp;spn=0,0&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
```

Alguém teria uma solução para isso?
Pensei em utilizar o `API` do maps para gerar os códigos, mas como são vários lugares (aprox. 10), poderia gerar algum conflito ou até seria difícil resgatar as coordenadas do banco de dados para inseri-las ao `javascript`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui encontrar a solução, bem besta e simples por sinal.

Apenas refiz o endereço que estava linkando o `iframe` para:

https://maps.google.com.br/maps?q=COORDENADA&output=embed&dg=oo

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Vamos ver se entendi, o que você precisa é colocar diversos pontos no mapa e setar o zoom para o usuário visualizar todos?

Se eu entendi certo, você pode sim usar a API do Google Maps. Apliquei algo neste sentido para carregar referências de cliente. Para o meu caso, fiz da seguinte forma:

JavaScript

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: {MODULO: "<?=$_POST["MODULO"]?>", TELA:"<?=$_POST["TELA"]?>", LATSUL: ne.lat(), LNGSUL: ne.lng(), LATNORTE: sw.lat() , LNGNORTE: sw.lng()},
      url: urlBase + "/principal.php?ACAO=CarregarReferencias",
      success: function(result){
        dadosMapa = mapa.data.addGeoJson(JSON.parse(result)); 
        mapa.data.setStyle(function(feature) {
            return {icon:"<?php echo URLBASE; ?>Imagens/referencePoint.png",title: feature.getProperty("nome")};
        }); 
      },
       beforeSend: function(){
           $(".clCarregando").show();
       },
       complete: function(msg){
           $(".clCarregando").hide();
           QtdReferencias = dadosMapa.length;
            $("#spnQtdRef").html(QtdReferencias);
       }
    });
```

E no PHP eu busquei do banco de dados as minhas referencias:

```
public function CarregarReferencias($ClienteId, $LatSul, $LngSul, $LatNorte, $LngNorte) {
    if ($LatSul < $LatNorte){
        $whereLat = "AND R.Latitude BETWEEN {$LatSul} AND {$LatNorte}";
    } else {
        $whereLat = "AND R.Latitude BETWEEN {$LatNorte} AND {$LatSul}";
    }

    if ($LngSul < $LngNorte){
        $whereLng = "AND R.Longitude BETWEEN {$LngSul} AND {$LngNorte}";
    } else {
        $whereLng = "AND R.Longitude BETWEEN {$LngNorte} AND {$LngSul}";
    }

    $sql = "SELECT R.Latitude AS LAT, R.Longitude AS LNG, R.Descricao AS REFERENCIA
    FROM Referencias RC
    INNER JOIN Referencias R ON (RC.ReferenciasId = R.ReferenciasId)
    WHERE ClienteId = {$ClienteId} AND R.Latitude <> 0 AND R.Longitude <> 0  $whereLat  $whereLng and R.status > 0";
    $this->bd->Clear ();
    $this->bd->setSQL ( $sql );

    $tmp = '{"type": "FeatureCollection","features": [';
    if ($this->bd->Executar ()) {               

        foreach ( $this->bd->Registro as $registro ) {
            $tmp.='{ "type": "Feature", "geometry": { "type": "Point",  "coordinates": [ '. $registro->Campo ["LNG"] .', '. $registro->Campo ["LAT"] .' ]}, "properties": { "nome": "'. str_replace("'", '`', str_replace('"', '`', $registro->Campo ["REFERENCIA"])) .'" } },';
        }
        $tmp = substr($tmp, 0, -1);

    } 
    $this->Lista = $tmp.']}';
    $this->Lista = json_decode($this->Lista);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Bem, uma alternativa seria registrar todos os locais num mesmo mapa, e quando selecionar o local, ele vai até a marcação correspondente. O problema é que quando você escolhe o local no `select`, o bloco do conteúdo dá um refresh, pois além de aparecer o mapa, é listada as informações do local..